# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method on Android Studio

Tags: android, database, android-volley

I am making an application in Android Studio, using an external database with php, but I got stuck in a part where I get an "ID" from the database, from that ID I determine if the user who enters must go to one or the other class, but it gives me the following error when I see the Logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.tallerof.MainActivity$5.onResponse(MainActivity.java:139)
    at com.example.tallerof.MainActivity$5.onResponse(MainActivity.java:132)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:83)
    at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:106)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

These are the lines of code where the error appears but I don't see that it could be wrong:

```
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        IdR.setText(jsonObject.getString("Id_Registered"));//Here is from where I get the error
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

IdR is a EditText and it is globally declared in the activity

Comment: But did you initialize `IdR`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IdR` is `null`.
You need to initialize it before using it.

Something like this:

```
IdR = findViewById(R.id.idr_view_id)
```

Comment: It was that, thanks, and what a shame to have asked just for that ...